I get an error when trying to use bstfun::as_forest_plot
When trying to use as_forest_plot from the bstfun package, I get an error :
Error in select():
ℹ In argument: all_of(c("label", col_names)).
Caused by error in all_of():
! Can't subset elements that don't exist.
✖ Element ci doesn't exist.

library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
library(bstfun)

mod <- glm(
   response ~ grade * age + trt,
   data = trial,
   family = binomial
)

This works:
mod %>%
   tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
   add_inline_forest_plot()

This does not:
mod %>%
   tbl_regression() %>%
   as_forest_plot()

I get the follonwing error: Error in select(): ℹ In argument:all_of(c("label", col_names)). Caused by error in all_of(): ! Can't subset elements that don't exist. ✖ Element ci doesn't exist. Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

I would make a bug report to the GitHub repository for this one. https://github.com/MSKCC-Epi-Bio/bstfun
